# Timing constraints vs. NOP in timing diagram of IS42S16320D SDRAM

Tags: fpga, sdram

I'm working with an FPGA that works at 50MHz and the IS42S16320D SDRAM.

The datasheet of the RAM assumes a clock of at least 100MHz.

Given the following timing diagram:
[image]

The $t_RCD$ is 18ns which means 1 cycle at 50MHz and 2 cycles at 100MHz.
The question is: Are these NOPs obligatory or are they used to visualize the needed extra cycle at 100MHz?
Or in other words: When I have some timing constraint given in the diagram and a NOP - how do I read that correctly?
At least 18ns (visualized by that NOP) or at least 18ns AND at least one NOP cycle?

These things happen a lot in that data sheet. Sometimes (like in the READ to WRITE situation where you have to have at least 3 DQM high cycles before writing) these NOPs are explicitly explained but mostly they are just accompanying a timing constraint.

Answer (score 1):

See the section "CHIP OPERATION" in the spec pdf, the wording there is pretty clear.

The bank must be activated, and it takes some arbitrary time. You're obliged to not issue any read/write commands until that time had passed, and the NOP is exactly the state of "not issuing the commands".

That section in doc tells you to divide the required tRCD time by the clock period, then round up the value to nearest integer. You round things to the edge of the clock because read/wride commands are issued synchronously to the clock, while the bank activation completion is asynchronous event.

You can wait longer than tRCD, there are no specific number of clocks to wait. It's just normally you'd want to spend the absolute minimum there, while not being allowed to issue commands before tRCD elapsed. So you start the command on nearest clock edge after the tRCD, that's all that matters.